Recharts Area chart is displaying in the incorrect position
I used a rechart library to visualize my data. But the rechart area chart is displayed y-axis values incorrectly. like Y-axis value: 107 but it's showing on position 70.
The chart area should display up to the position indicated by the tooltip marker.
See the screenshots below.
Here is the sample code

change chart type to monotone. Now it works.
Ref: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/4713
